# Como reemplazar datos de una matriz en un orden en especifico

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

tengo este problema en el que se tienen que reemplazar los lugares que estan "Disponibles" por nombres que ingrese el usuario en un orden de derecha a izquierda y de abajo hacia arriba hasta reemplazar todos los lugares disponibles de la matriz.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([["Armando", "Disponible"], 
            ["Narciso", "Anahi"], 
            ["Disponible", "Disponible"], 
            ["Alexis", "Rigel"]])
```

Puedo reemplazar manualmente alguna parte de la matriz,

```
a[2,1]= "Alan"
print(a)
[['Armando' 'Disponible']
['Narciso' 'Anahi']
['Disponible' 'Alan']
['Alexis' 'Rigel']]
```

Pero no se de que manera puedo hacer que se recorra la matriz y reemplazce los lugares que estan disponibles

Answer (score 0):

este es el codigo que te propongo:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([["Armando", "Disponible"], 
            ["Narciso", "Anahi"], 
            ["Disponible", "Disponible"], 
            ["Alexis", "Rigel"]])

#Creo una funcion para no repetir el codigo          
def reemplazarDisponible(nombre):
    #Se crea el primer bucle para recorrer todas las filas de la matriz
    for i in range(0,4):
        #Se crea el segundo bucle para recorrer todas las columnas de cada fila
        for j in range(0,2):
            if(a[i,j] == "Disponible"):
                #Se compara cada uno de los valores de la matriz para comprobar que sea igual que "Disponible"
                a[i,j]= nombre #En caso de que sea igual a "Disponible", se cambia por el nombre pasado por parametro a la funcion
                return a #Se devuelve la funcion. En caso de no poner esta linea, se cambiarian todos los "Disponible" por el mismo nombre!!


print(reemplazarDisponible("Marcos"))
print(reemplazarDisponible("Claudia"))
print(reemplazarDisponible("Roberto"))
```

PD: Como dijo el compañero, se debe comentar el codigo de la explicacion para mejor entendimiento pero con las prisas se me paso :).
Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: Sería útil que le explicaras al OP que hicistes y como funciona, para que sepa hacerlo sólo en el futuro. Un código sin explicación no es útil